# Am I converting to BIGINT incorrectly? I am still getting this error: Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int

Tags: sql, error-handling, overflow, bigint

This is my code:

```
SELECT CONVERT(bigint, COUNT (DISTINCT ID)) AS Total
```

is it simply because the result is larger than 19 digits? Please help!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax suggests that you are using SQL Server.  If so, you can use:

```
SELECT COUNT_BIG(DISTINCT ID) as Total
```

Your code does not work.  It says to convert the *result* of the `COUNT()` to a `BIGINT`.  However, the overflow is occurring in the `COUNT()`.